# On a certain series of complex numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

Is it possible that the above infinite series is equal to

[image]

?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: Also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Related_formulas

Comment: Try your formula with $n=1,2,3,4$ and compare to the initial series. You will see that your result is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $i$ has periodic powers ie:
$$i^1=i, i^2=-1,  i^3=-i, i^4=1, i^5=i$$
Etc. Note the period of four.
So due to the fact that consecutive odd and consecutive even powers are the negatives of one another we can say that the sum can be deduced simply by taking the modulo of $n$
Thus if $n$  $mod 4=1$ the sum equals $i$
If it is $2$ then the sum is $i-1$ 
If it is $3$ then the sum is $-1$ and if it is zero  modulo $4$ then the sum is $0$

Comment: So, if I just simply add a "1" at the begining of the serie e.g: 1+i+i^2...+i^n would the sum be 1 if the power mod 4=0 right? I just had that serie in a quick test and didn't stop to think about it, just took the serie and used the Arithmetic formula

Comment: Yes it would and you should have used the geometric series sum formula

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed sum for the series $s(n)=\frac{i^n(1+i)}{2}$ is wrong, as can easily be demonstrated by counter-example: for the $n=1$ case your sum gives $i=\frac{i-1}{2}$, which is false.

The series is a simple geometric progression, and we can use the familiar formula for the sum of a finite geometric series to obtain:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^k=\frac{i-i^{n+1}}{1-i}.$$

Comment: I just thought that applying the complex properties (i^2 = -1) would make of it a non-geometric serie, so, it would be alternating between 1, -1 depending on the exponent was odd or even. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Alex.Unger First of all, the integer powers of $i$ cycle through four possible values, not just two. See cirpis's response for details. Second of all, the only thing that matters when deciding if a series is geometric or not is if all pairs of consecutive terms have a common ratio. In this case the common ratio is $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to proceed than geometric series, is by noting that
 $$i + i^2 +i^3 + i^4 = i-1-i+1=0.$$ So for any $ k,m \in \mathbb{N},0\leq k \leq 3,m \geq 1, n = 4m+k,$ we have
$$\sum_{s=1}^{4m+k} i^s = \sum_{t=0}^{m-1}i^{t}\underbrace{(i + i^2 +i^3 + i^4)}_{=0} +\underbrace{i^{4m}}_{=1}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}i^l\right) = \sum_{l=0}^{k}i^l %=\left\{\begin{array}{l l} 1 &\text{if } k=0 \\ 1+i &\text{if } k=1 \\ i &\text{if } k=2 \\ 0 &\text{if } k=3\end{array} \right.$$